# How to reorder the include path in CMake

Tags: cmake

The default include path in CMake is `/usr/include` on Linux, however having it in the first position interferers with the installation of same software compiled with different compilers.
How can I reorder the path so that the system include path is move to the last position?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be set your own INCLUDE env var. See this supersuser [post](https://superuser.com/questions/488173/how-can-i-edit-the-path-on-linux), which tells you how and where to put your custom environment variables on linux systems once user logon.